error: command 'C:\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
Full error code
PS C:\Users\Gotit\PycharmProjects\Freelance> pip install pybgs
Collecting pybgs
  Using cached pybgs-3.3.0.post2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pybgs
  Building wheel for pybgs (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      cmake -HC:\Users\Gotit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-liaez_iy\pybgs_67740e6363414abc8d9262ddc101ccec -Bbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Gotit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\py
thon.exe -DBGS_CORE_STATIC=ON -DBGS_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DBGS_PYTHON_ONLY=ON -DBGS_PYTHON_VERSION=3.10
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.
     
        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Running
     
         'nmake' '-?'
     
        failed with:
     
         no such file or directory
     
     
      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      error: command 'C:\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybgs
  Running setup.py clean for pybgs
Failed to build pybgs
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pybgs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have Cmake installed in the path C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
64 bit version
Cmake installed in path (CMake command is not recognized)
Also I installed the library pip3 install cmake (error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory)
I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time, so I decided to publish it here

Why have you searched for error messages like command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory and 'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, if you got completely different error message?
